# searching with window.find and a list in browser console

Tags: javascript, console.log

In the console when I type `windows.find("text")` it gives me "true" or "false", which is good.

To make my job easier in checking if a list of items is present in a webpage, I want to make a script in the console

1. list - `var mylist = ["text1", "text2", "text3"]`
2. run a loop, which checks `for i=0, i<mylist.length, i++* if windows.find(mylist[i])`
3. and if it is true, to list the word in the console.log.

Could you please help me with the syntax?  Is my approach correct?

Comment: Try `for (var i=0, i<mylist.length, i++) console.log(mylist[i],windows.find(mylist[i]));` - also look into `bookmarklet`

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like

```
var mylist = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];

for(var val of mylist){
    if(window.find(val)) console.log(val);
}
```

Should do the trick? In chrome you should be able to just paste it in etc.

Edit: Adding none ES6 example also

```
var mylist = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];

for (var i=0;i<mylist.length;i++){
    if(window.find(mylist[i])) console.log(mylist[i]);
}
```

Comment: ES6 - I suggest just fixing his `for (var i=0;i<mylist.length;i++) ...` unless he is using Chrome or Edge browser

Comment: I initially thought it was a typo of for in

Comment: Ps the other example is identical to my comment :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't notice you got there first :P Could change mine to a for/in for variation - my es6 one did start as that, but i thought the es6 syntax looked more readable.

Comment: Please don't I almost voted you down for using for in over an array ;) not recommended

Comment: thanks guys, really appreciate it! 

with the correct syntax it does recognize some of the list items, but doesn't recognize others. checked with some other browsers, but it seems like window.find does not work on internet explorer or edge; only on google chrome. do you know another command that functions in the same way?

Comment: `document.body.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf("word1") !== -1` should probably do what you need. Ie. `if(document.body.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf("word1") !== -1) console.log("word1");`

Comment: var mylist = ["Word1", "Word2", "Word3"]
for (var i=0;i<mylist.length;i++){
 if(document.body.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(mylist[i]) !== -1) console.log(mylist[i]); }

this returns undefined... :(

Comment: It should console log any matched words - but yea, the actual output would be undefined (since it never returns anything). That said, I'm actually lower casing the text in my example so, "Word1" would never match. Try using `if(document.body.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(mylist[i].toLowerCase()) !== -1) console.log(mylist[i]);` instead, which will lowercase your inputs too (giving you a case insensitive search)